# Iterate over a table row by row snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table of meal pre order, some columns have nulls so i would like to update these. I want to update the nulls with a random selection from a 'meals' table. But the customer cant have a meal that they have already ordered.
Eg my table of orders:

| customer | option1 | option2 | option3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 145 | pizza | pasta | null |
| 245 | null | flan | null |

my table of meals:

| meal |
| --- |
| steak |
| pizza |
| flan |
| pasta |
| fish |
| etc |

I want to select a random meal from the meal table to fill in the nulls for the customer. But the customer cannot receive a meal they have already listed.
Eg for customer 145 they cannot receive a pizza or pasta in option3.

These tables are hundreds of rows so cannot be done mannually.

Ive tried the following but it ends up looking at what exists in the full column rather than  what the indiv customer has already ordered. How can i look at the customer in isolation?

```
update ordertable set T.option1 = S.meal from 
(select * from mealtable 
 where meal not in (select distinct option1 from ordertable where order1 is null)
                and meal not in (select distinct option2 from ordertable where order1 is null)
                and meal not in  (select distinct option3 from ordertable where order1 is null)
             
 ORDER BY RANDOM()
                    LIMIT 1) S
```

thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use array functions and 3 separate updates for this. To make sure the update doesn't assign the same meal to all the customer, `uniform` function can be used to randomly pick a meal from the possible options.

```
create or replace temporary table t (customer int, opt1 varchar, opt2 varchar, opt3 varchar) as

select 1, 'pizza', 'pasta', null union all
select 2, null, 'flan', null union all
select 3, null, null, 'pizza' union all
select 4, 'fish', null, 'flan' union all
select 5, null, null, null union all
select 6, null, 'eggs', null union all
select 7, null, 'fish', null union all
select 8, 'pizza', 'pasta', null union all
select 9, null, 'flan', 'fish' union all
select 10, null, null, null;
```

---

```
create or replace temporary table meals(meal varchar) as

select value::varchar
from table(flatten(['steak','pizza','flan','pasta','fish','bolognese','soup','cereal','eggs','salad']));
```

---

```
set num_opt = (select count(meal)-1-3 from meals); --subtracting 1 since array slices are 0 based and then another 3 to exclude at most 3 instances of non-null opt1, opt2, and opt3

update t
set opt1 = coalesce(opt1, array_except((select array_agg(meal) from meals),[opt1,opt2,opt3])[uniform(0, $num_opt, random(40))]);

update t
set opt2 = coalesce(opt2, array_except((select array_agg(meal) from meals),[opt1,opt2,opt3])[uniform(0, $num_opt, random(40))]);

update t
set opt3 = coalesce(opt3, array_except((select array_agg(meal) from meals),[opt1,opt2,opt3])[uniform(0, $num_opt, random(40))]);

select * 
from t;
```